# parallel sorting methods

Tags: algorithm

```
in book algorithm in c++ by robert sedgewick
```

there is such kind of  problem
how many parallel steps would be  required to sort  n records   that are distributed  on some k disks(let say k=1000 or any value ) and using    some m processors the same m  can be 100 or arbitrary number
     i have questions
      what we should  do in such case? what are methods to solve such kind of problems?
    and what is answer in this case?

Comment: General way to solve homework is to read the course materials.

Comment: Yes this guy is obviously just posting every one of his homework questions without any work. Stop helping him.

Comment: Sean owen   please look at my posted questions and please stop such talking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, initially you divide the n records over k disks and sort them. Assuming you use an n Log(n) sort, this will take (n/k)log(n/k) time.

Then, you have to merge the sorted lists. You can do this in parallel. Each merge step will take o(length of list).

Initially the length of the lists are n/k, and at the end the length is 1.

So this will take

2n/k  (have to merge each pair of n/k lists into a single list size 2n/k)

then it's 4n/k .... up to kn/k

so it's  (2 + 4 + ... k) * (n/k)
which is log2(k)

so this step is log2(k) * (n/k)

so order of algorithm is (n/k)log(n/k) + log2(k) * (n/k)